# What are advantages in compilation when declaring methods in hpp files

Tags: c++, header

In `hpp` files we have declarations of methods, and in `cpp` files we have definitions of methods. If I made only change in `cpp` file in method that is declared in `hpp` header file. Does recompilation is needed? If yes, what is advantage of using `hpp` file in **THIS CASE**?

I read other topics about that, and they do not answer directly why using `hpp` is better in that case.

Comment: I think one of those "declaration" should be a "definition", right?

Comment: Templates. 'nuff-said.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, recompilation is needed when you change something in a `cpp` file.

The reason we keep **declarations** (`.h` or `.hpp`) separate from **definitions** (`.cpp`), is really straightforward - it's the easiest way to keep things simple and working.

1. The system simplifies **including** declarations in various other files,
2. You can **distribute** the header files without the definitions, if you compile the project to a `lib`, `dll`.
3. You can avoid **recompiling** classes that include other headers when you change something in a `*.cpp` associated with the included `*.h` file. In that case - only **one** class needs to be recompilled, instead of all of them (note: this is true only if you leave the header untouched.).

There are however some cases when you **don't** want the files separate. That's the case with `templates` and `inline` methods.

Comment: How does it decreases ammount of recompilation if we have `hpp` and `cpp` file and we change something in `cpp` file INSTEAD having everything in `java` or `cs` file in Java and C#? Mam egzamin dyplomowy i jedno z zagadnień  Deklarowanie i definiowanie funkcji w C++.  i w sumie nie wiem co powiedzieć, zwłaszcza że c++ mnie nie interesuje ; ), ani nawet u mnie w szkole nie jest wykorzystywany zbytnio poza robotyką i grami komputerowymi

Comment: Wybacz, ale będzie po angielsku, żeby inni skorzystali :) So: it doesn't decrease the number of recompilations. The idea behind the system is purelly aesthetic. On the exam you should probably know __how__ to declare and define functions, not __why__ :) Also - you should know the difference between a _declaration_ and a _definition_.

Comment: Indeed it *does* decrease the needed number of recompilations. If your hpp file is included by 5 cpp files and you change the corresponding cpp file only one recompilation is necessary. If you would combine declaration and definition 5 recompilations would become necessary.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point! Gonna add that up. I was more thinking of the compilation process as a whole, not `*.o` recompiling.

Comment: I am creating cpp bindings for a C library "lib.h", I have a "lib.hpp" that includes "lib.h" and a "lib.cpp" file that includes "lib.hpp". Both "lib.hpp" and "lib.cpp" use functions from "lib.h". So do I have any benefit from seperate hpp and cpp file ? Even if I create a dll from "lib.cpp", wouldn't "lib.h" still be compiled when "lib.hpp" is included by end user ?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case it safes you from the need to have to recompile *every* cpp file that includes the hpp file containing the declaration of the changed constructs.

---

Usually your header file (.h or .hpp) contains only declarations. Of course there are exceptions, for example a lot of compilers still can't handle separate declaration and definition of template classes, but for simplicity lets stick to that.
Furthermore you could say that a declaration gives the compiler all the information it need to get the needed information of e.g. a class to know how to use it.

- Size it needs to allocate for an instance of this class
- Callable methods of the class
- If the class is polymorphic
- etc.

So the header file contains not only the interface of the class but also some additional information the compiler needs to know about your class.

If you want to use the class you defined in a header file you need to include it. C++ compilers compile each cpp file seperately. But first the preprocessor expands the source file. That means it expands all #defines for example. But it also recursively replaces all #include directives with the corresponding file. This is called a translation unit.

The compiler then takes this translation unit and compiles it into an object file. All object files get then linked together by the linker to form your binary file. However, compilers usually come with some kind of optimization. They can detect if the translation unit changed since the last compilation. They then only compile it, if it is necessary because changes were made.

Therefore if you make changes to a header file which is included in different cpp files, the translation unit of all these source files will change and the compiler will have to rebuild the corresponding object files. However, if you can limit the changes to be only in your cpp file, then only ONE translation unit changes and has to be recompiled.

In big projects this optimization can reduce build times from hours to minutes. There are even programming techniques that aim at reducing the dependencies between files to achieve faster compilation times. For example the Pimpl idiom can be used to reduce dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

hpp file can be included into multiple cpp files. Moreover it can be included into multiple hpp files. So when you change hpp file, every cpp file which includes it directly or through another hpp file should be recompiled. When you change cpp file only that single cpp file should be recompiled. The difference is huge for a big project.